# What is s in std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s)?

Tags: c++, c++14

I find the [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) can process the time unit s.

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
```

But I don't know what the `s` in `2s` is.

Comment: 2 seconds. ["UDL"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s

Comment: @UnholySheep, Great, I see. operator can be a letter in the C++14

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> #### What is `s` in `std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s)`?

`s` is a **user-defined literal** making `2s` a literal value of type [`chrono::second`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

---

## Built-in literals

You might be familiar with [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [floating literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal); those are built-in suffixes:

```
+--------+---------+---------------+
| Suffix | Example |     Type      |
+--------+---------+---------------+
|      U |     42U | unsigned int  |
|     LL |     1LL | long long int |
|      f |   3.14f | float         |
+--------+---------+---------------+
```

They let you provide a literal value whose type matches your needs. For example:

```
int   half(int n)   { return n/2; }
float half(float f) { return f/2; }
half(3);   // calls the int   version, returns 1    (int)
half(3.f); // calls the float version, returns 1.5f (float)
```

## User-defined literals

C++11 added a new feature: [user-defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) suffixes:

> Allows integer, floating-point, character, and string literals to produce objects of user-defined type by defining a user-defined suffix.

#### Syntax

They allow to provide a literal of a user-defined type or a Standard Library-defined type. Defining a literal is as easy as defining the `operator""`:

```
// 0_<suffix> is now a <type> literal
<type> operator "" _<suffix>(unsigned long long); // ull: one of the height existing forms
```

#### Example

```
#include <iostream>

class Mass
{
    double _value_in_kg;
public:
    Mass(long double kg) : _value_in_kg(kg) {}
    friend Mass          operator+ (Mass const& m1, Mass const& m2)  { return m1._value_in_kg + m2._value_in_kg; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Mass const& m) { return os << m._value_in_kg << " kg"; }
};

Mass operator "" _kg(long double kg) { return Mass{kg}; }
Mass operator "" _lb(long double lb) { return Mass{lb/2.20462}; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << 3.0_kg + 8.0_lb  << '\n';
}
```

[Outputs "6.62874 kg" (demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3257a5b380b8bf) as [it should](https://www.google.fr/search?q=3kg+%2B+8lb).

## The case of `std::chrono`

Unlike "real" user-provided literals, the Standard Library provides literals not starting with an underscore (`_`). `s` is one of them and is defined in [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s) (since C++14):

```
constexpr chrono::seconds operator "" s(unsigned long long secs);
```

With other duration literals, it let you write something as pretty as:

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
const auto world_marathon_record_2018 = 2h + 1min + 39s;
```

Comment: Ironically _not_ defined by the user 

Comment: Is it possible to bind to a single literal instead of bringing the whole `chrono_literals` namespace to scope, something like `using std::chrono::operator "" s;`, without triggering MSVC warning C4455?

Comment: @MohammedSafwat Your comment brought me here. IMHO this is a bug, see (and vote) [in MS dev community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/incorrect-warning-when-using-standard-string-liter/673948)

Comment: @Brandlingo Thanks for pointing me to the bug report; I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

"s" stands for second and actually a literal operator defined in standard library. Literals are part of C++14 standard. You may access them by `using namespace std::chrono_literals;`

Answer (score -1):

s in this expression is actually a chrono library function which is defined in Standard library